# How to use GSON equivalent in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So basically, I am trying to find a runtime serializer/deserializer that is equivalent to GSON. I could also use instead a dart class method generator (fromJson() and toJson()) and preferably it being an IDE plugin generator. I already tried "json_serializable" dart package though it was a somewhat ugly solution since it wouldn't work right (doesn't work with private variables)

Answer (score 0):

While GSON uses java reflections in runtime to serialize objects, it's impossible to use Dart's runtime reflections in Flutter (dart:mirrors package is not allowed in framework).

When deserializing from json, there's no way to set a value of private field without exposing it (by making public) or adding a setter.